# 'str' object has no attribute 'isin' error while using period_range in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I am trying to format a date column that I am reading from a csv file but I am getting Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2999-12-31 00:00:00 error while formatting the high date. To solve this, I tried to use period_range as given below:

```
 low_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
 high_date = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
 r = pd.period_range(low_date,high_date)
 for i in range(len(Df[date])): 
     if Df[date][i].isin(r):
        Df[date] = pd.to_datetime(Df[date]).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0")
```

Now I am getting error as given below:
**Error**
**if Df[date][i].isin(r):**

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Please help in fixing the error. I am trying to fix the out of bounds error for the high date and now getting this error which I am not able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

## The Error

In your code...

```py
 low_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
 high_date = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
 r = pd.period_range(low_date,high_date)
 for i in range(len(Df[date])): 
     if Df[date][i].isin(r):
        Df[date] = pd.to_datetime(Df[date]).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0")
```

your conditional fails because `Df[date][i]` is the value in `DF` at position `[i, date]`.

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["abc"]})
df["date"][0]

# >>> "abc"
```

You probably want something more like `DF[date][i] in r` or preferably `DF[date].isin(r)`.

## My Suggestion

`pandas` has a lot of vectorized methods that may offer a speedup and simplify some of your code.

We could convert and format all values in your `DF[date]` column using [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```py
DF[date] = DF[date].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0")
```

You can also add the conditional to the method:

```py
DF[date] = DF[date].apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row) if row in r else row).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0")
```

## All Together

```py
low_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' 
high_date = '2999-12-31 00:00:00'
r = pd.period_range(low_date,high_date)
DF[date] = DF[date].apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row) if row in r else row).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.0")
```